# JQUERY : How to loop Array disableTimeRanges from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, timepicker

how to display all indexes from array to disableTimeRanges array?
this my code

```
<input id="tanggal" type="date">
<input id="horaInicio" type="text" class="time" />

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tanggal').on('change', function() {
            var tanggal = $(this).val();
                if(tanggal) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{url("/tanggal")}}/'+encodeURI(tanggal),
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(data) {
                    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                        $('#horaInicio').timepicker('remove').timepicker({'disableTimeRanges': [ [value['dari'], value['sampai']], ] });
                        });
                    }
                });
                }
               });
            });
    </script>
```

index [0] : 3:00am, 4:00am

index [1] : 6:00am, 9:00am

but my code just displays the last index, I want to display all of my indexes. thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are overwriting the `disableTimeRanges` property for "each" array element. So only the last one is recorded.

To fix this refer to the sample from the documentation:

```
$('#disableTimeRangesExample').timepicker({
    'disableTimeRanges': [
        ['1am', '2am'],
        ['3am', '4:01am']
    ]
});
```

So first, transform the data from the server to match this format and place it into a new array. Then simply pass the array into the 'disableTimeRanges' property.

**Change:**

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    $('#horaInicio').timepicker('remove').timepicker(
      {'disableTimeRanges': [[value['dari'], value['sampai']], ] });
});
```

**To:**

```
let exclusions = data.map(item=>[item.value['Dari'], item.value['sampan']]);
$('#horaInicio').timepicker('remove').timepicker(
          {'disableTimeRanges': exclusions });
```

Comment: hai randy, I got some error at (item->[item.value['Dari'], item.value['sampan']]);

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >

thanks before

Comment: Been writing too much Java - this: `->` should be `=>`. Sorry about mistake, answer has been corrected.

Comment: you're perfect!

Comment: I'm tried to vote your answer but I can't vote because

stackoverflow said


Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Thanks! I just voted up your question - it was well formed and made it easy for me to answer. That should help.

Comment: hard code is working but when I get data from server with ajax is not working. Is there any solution for this.

Comment: @Monzur - Please create a new question that refers to this one (use the share link on my answer as reference) - in your new question, include the JSON that is coming from the server. I, or someone else, will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract '$('#horaInicio').timepicker' outside from the foreach loop.

Inside the foreach just build an array and make the timepicker reference to it.